# How to return the UPS shipping quote from opening the ups page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script that I send to UPS, and the UPS page calculates the shipping cost.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#shipping').submit(function(e){
  var url = [
    "http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi?accept_UPS_license_agreement=yes",
    "10_action=3",
    "13_product="+ $('* [name="selService"]').val(),
    "14_origCountry="+ $('* [name="txtFromCountry"]').val(),
    "15_origPostal="+ $('* [name="txtFromZip"]').val(),
    "origCity="+ $('* [name="txtFromCity"]').val(),
    "19_destPostal="+ $('* [name="txtToZip"]').val(),
    "20_destCity="+ $('* [name="txtToCity"]').val(),
    "22_destCountry="+ $('* [name="txtToCountry"]').val(),
    "23_weight="+ $('* [name="txtPackWeight"]').val(),
    "47_rateChart="+ $('* [name="selRate"]').val(),
    "48_container="+ $('* [name="selPackaging"]').val(),
    "49_residential="+ $('* [name="selResidential"]').val(),
    "25_length="+ $('* [name="txtPackLength"]').val(),
    "26_width="+ $('* [name="txtPackWidth"]').val(),
    "27_height="+ $('* [name="txtPackHeight"]').val()
  ].join('&');

  window.open(url); //you want to split output by '%' for it to make sense
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

How do I get it to return the shipping value it generates back to my script. In PHP I would use something like:

```
  $fp = fopen($url, "r");
  while(!feof($fp)){
    $result = fgets($fp, 500);
    $result = explode("%", $result);
    $errcode = substr($result[0], -1);
    switch($errcode){
      case 3:
        $returnval = $result[8];
            break;
    }
  }
```

but I am trying to do this 100% javascript/Jquery.
Please help.

Comment: Let jQuery build the querystring for you.  You aren't escaping anything properly.  Just pass the URL, as well as a data object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing  window.open(url);

You simply use an ajax function,  It seems you are wanting to do a get request looking at the url being generated...

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) {
    // data is the returned data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make requests to the other domain "ups.com" do to security concerns if you do you will get an error like the following

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ups.com/usin... 
  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
  header is present on the requested resource. 
  Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Research the term "Cross Site Scripting".